# DSN Shows tables in Microsoft Access but not in Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi

I have created a DSN for an ODBC connection in my desktop to connect to Power BI.
My Back-end for the ODBC connection is **IBM Informix**.

Through Get Data, I selected ODBC Connection and selected the DSN that was just created from the lists available. But I am ***not able to see any tables*** under the DSN in the navigator menu.

I used the same DSN as an linked table in Microsoft Access and it is showing all the tables under that particular DSN.

Both of the **Microsoft Access and Power BI Desktop are 64-bits**.

```
let
    Source = Odbc.DataSource("dsn=CMS_Testing", [HierarchicalNavigation=true])
in
    Source
```

This is my source-code that was generated in the Power BI. I couldn't proceed further as Power BI didn't show me the tables under the DSN.

> The DSN is a Machine and User type data source.

Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

IBM says:To configure a DSN on the Windows 64-bit platform, you must use the 32-bit ODBC Data Source Administrator:
C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
Sometimes you have to find the file and open it directly on a 64-bit machine. If you just search for ODBC connector you will see the 64 bit connector.